# Latex \newcommand problem

Tags: latex

can someone please tell what I'm doing wrong here?

```
\newcommand{\bc}{\small\begin{verbatim}}
\newcommand{\ec}{\normalsize\end{verbatim}}
```

and then

```
\bc
1  3       6 7 89 10
 22 7  7  45
\ec
```

but I get

```
Runaway argument?
^^M1  3       6 7 89 10^^M 22 7  7  45^^M\ec^^M^^M\section{Reading on\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> i4c.tex

? 
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> i4c.tex
```

I thought it was pretty safe to do that, since most commands are just text substitutions... any hints?

Comment: Belongs on http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've said this before, but this proliferation of "stackexchange" stuff is ridiculous. Soon it will be error.newcommand.tex.stackexchange.com... Whatever happened to the idea of centralizing knowledge? What are tags for then? Gee, someone has a good idea and it then it explodes into a myriad of stupid ones.

Comment: Good point about `error.newcommand.tex.stackexchange.com`. Excellent. my thoughts. My internet browser can not accommodate so many tabs.

Comment: Are you just trying to save keystrokes? Try to find an editor that does abbreviation expansion. (Or use something like AutoHotKey or AutoKey that will do text expansion in any editor.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How `\begin{verbatim}` works. briefly and roughly.

1. `\begin{verbatim}` is expanded to `\verbatim`.
2. Then `\verbatim` sets category code of each special characters to 12. 
   Now all chars is like digits or puncts.
3. Then `\verbatim` sets font, parindent and calls `\@xverbatim`.
4. `\@xverbatim` catches the end of verbatim using the following trick:

   ```
   \def\@xverbatim#1\end{#1\end}
   ```
5. Then \end{verbatim} finishes work.

How `newcommand{\bc}{\small\begin{verbatim}}` works.

1. `\bс` expands to `\small\begin{verbatim}`.
2. Then `\begin{verbatim}` expands to `\varbatim`. 
    `\varbatim` changes all categories and font.
3. Then `\verbatim` calls `\@xverbatim`.
4. `\@xverbatim` tries to catch your argument using the following trick:

   ```
   \def\@xverbatim#1\end{#1\end}
   ```

   but it is impossible because of `\@xverbatim` tries to catch
     `\end` where all letters (`\`,`e`,`n`,`d`) have the category 12 and 11.
     But in fact there are only `\ec` exsits.
5. `\@xverbatim` is trying and trying to find `\end` where backslash (`\`) has category 12 but.... `File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim`

Answer (score 2):

`verbatim` is special, it scans for a *literal* `\end{verbatim}`, as any macro substitutions are not executed after the `\begin{verbatim}`.

Answer (score 2):

Some environment, such as `verbatim`, need to scan in the text ahead to find their end manually. So unlike “normal” environments, `verbatim` needs to find the text `\end{verbatim}` in the input text, verbatim.

In your example, it doesn’t (since the input text contains `\ec` instead.

As a workaround, you can instead use the `fancyvrb` package that defines a `Verbatim` package and allows definition custom verbatim environments.